# How to get rid of intermittent IllegalArgumentException coming via method invocation using reflection

Tags: java, methods, reflection, protocol-buffers, proto

I have a requirement to convert a POJO object to its corresponding protobuf message. I am writing one utility which will use reflection and generate the protobuf message.

I have below POJO models -

```
public class Person {
   int id;
   Map<String,String> properties;
   String name;
   Address address;
   Gender gender;
}

public class Address {
   private String line1;
   private String line2;
   private String line3;
   private String City;
   private String state;
}

public enum Gender {
   MALE,FEMALE
}
```

Corresponding proto messages -

```
message PersonMsg {
  int32 id = 1;
  map<string, string> properties = 2;
  string name = 3;
  AddressMsg address = 4;
  Gender gender = 5;
}

message AddressMsg {
  string line1 = 1;
  string line2 = 2;
  string line3 = 3;
  string city = 4;
  string state = 5;
  string country = 6;
  string pincode = 7;
```

}

```
enum Gender{
  Gender_DEFAULT = 0;
  Gender_MALE = 1;
  Gender_FEMALE = 2;
}
```

The converter logic is like - for scalar/primitive types dynamically invoke the gette/setters and populate the data in the protobuf builder.
If fields are custom type (in this case Address field), then recursively call the method and populate the field -

````
private static GeneratedMessageV3 getMessage(Object o) throws ClassNotFoundException
    String protoName = o.getClass().getName()+"Proto";
    Class outerClass = Class.forName(protoName);
    String msgName = protoName+"$"+ o.getClass().getSimpleName()+"Msg";
    Class modelClass = o.getClass();
    Class protoMsg = Class.forName(msgName);

    try {
        Method method = protoMsg.getMethod("newBuilder", null);
        com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.Builder builder =  (com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.Builder)method.invoke(null, null);

        Field[] fields = o.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field field : fields){
            if(field.getType().isPrimitive() || field.getType().isAssignableFrom(String.class)){
                Method getMethod = modelClass.getMethod("get"+ CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL, field.getName()));
                Object value = getMethod.invoke(o, null);
                Method setMethod = findSetterMethod(builder.getClass(), field);
                setMethod.invoke(builder, value);
            } else if(field.getType().isEnum()){
                Method getMethod = modelClass.getMethod("get"+ CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL, field.getName()));
                Enum modelEnumValue = (Enum) getMethod.invoke(o, null);
                String protoEnumClassName = field.getType().getName()+"Proto$"+field.getType().getSimpleName();
                Class protoEnumClass = Class.forName(protoEnumClassName);
                Method enumMethod = protoEnumClass.getDeclaredMethod("values", null);
                Enum[] protoValues = (Enum[]) enumMethod.invoke(null, null);
                Enum protoValue = null;
                for(Enum value : protoValues){
                    if(value.name().replace(field.getType().getSimpleName()+"_", "").equals(modelEnumValue.name())){
                        protoValue = value;
                    }
                }
                if(protoValue!=null) {
                    Method setMethod = findSetterMethod(builder.getClass(), field);
                    setMethod.invoke(builder, protoValue);
                }
            } else if(Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType()) || Map.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())){
                if(Map.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())){
                    populateMap(o, field, builder);
                }
            } else{
                System.out.println("Field is custom type :"+ field.getName());
                Method getMethod = modelClass.getMethod("get"+ CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL, field.getName()));
                System.out.println("Found Getter Method :"+ getMethod);
                Object modelValue = getMethod.invoke(o, null);
                System.out.println("Model Value :"+ modelValue);
                Method setMethod = findSetterMethod(builder.getClass(), field);
                setMethod.invoke(builder, getMessage(modelValue));
            }
        }
        GeneratedMessageV3 msg = (GeneratedMessageV3) builder.build();
        return msg;
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}```
````

**This code works fine and convert the pojo objects to protobuf message.
But sometimes it intermittently fails at runtime with - **"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch"****

This is failing at line - **"setMethod.invoke(builder, getMessage(modelValue));"**

Any idea why this is failing if code is not changed at all in between the runs? How can i get rid/workaround this exception ?

Comment: Does the return value of `getMessage` match the argument type of the set method?

Comment: Method "getMessage" returns "GeneratedMessageV3" but the setter method expects "AddressMsg" (AddressMsg is itself child of GeneratedMessageV3). In this case this should every time. But I am getting this failure intermittently.

Comment: So, `AddressMsg` is a subtype of `GeneratedMessageV3`? The best, you can do, is to surround the invocation with a try-catch, and when the exception happens, print the exact types of the argument and the method signature of the setter.

Comment: Yeah when I printed it the setter method was wrong, protobuf generates methods with same name but different parameter types - 1 with Builder , 1 with msg it self. I was randomly picking up a method without checking the type parameter which was causing the issue. Thanks for helping to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in the method "findSetterMethod" was searching the setter method by name. So if name is matched then it returned the first method it found. Protobuf generates same name methods but with different parameters accepting - Builder, Protobuf message it self. So when a method with wrong type was selected, it used to fail. Fixed code to check for the correct argument type and its working fine now.